# Weird data mutation in JS object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm having an annoying thing happening with my array data in JS.

Here is the block of code:

```
console.log("------------pull-----------------");

// after all data is pulled
// then rebuild pData
cats.forEach(function (c) {
    console.log(c);
    pulled[i] = new Object();
    pulled[i].name = c;
    pulled[i].data = a[c];
    console.log(pulled[i].data);
    console.log(pulled[i]);
    console.log(pulled[i].data);
    pulled[i].color = colors[i++];
});
```

Here's the results that come from `console.log()`:

```
------------pull-----------------<br/>
Calculated Percent Change<br/>
[-0.624921793534932, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, max: function, min: function, sum: function]<br/>

Object {name: "Calculated Percent Change", data: Array[5]}<br/>
color: "#75B5CD"<br/>
data: Array[5]<br/>
0: "277.8"<br/>
1: "-44.5"<br/>
2: "-44.5"<br/>
3: "-44.5"<br/>
4: "-44.5"<br/>
length: 5<br/>
__proto__: Array[0]<br/>
name: "Calculated Percent Change"<br/>
__proto__: Object<br/>

[-0.624921793534932, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, max: function, min: function, sum: function]<br/>
```

What's happening here?
My initial array is correct.
But then, once I show the array in the object,
the numbers are all wonky and wrong.
I don't even know how these numbers are being calculated,
but then I do another test by accessing the array explicitly and it's right again

expected behaviour is that the array in the object has the same values as array when its printed out on the line beforehand, ie 0: -0.624..

Can anyone tell me what's up with this?

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Does `i` is defined outside the `forEach`? Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: hey @beterraba - i cannot create a fiddle cause this is a closed system and all the data is determined externally.  `i` is defined previous to this as `var i=0;`

Comment: you can wrap this piece of code in jsfiddle, initialise `cats` and log the results, then tell us what are the expected results.

Comment: oh i forgot mention - the expected behavious is that the array in the object has the same values as array when its printed out on the line beforehand, ie `0: -0.624`... etc

Comment: please learn the object literal syntax `{name: c, data: a[c]}`

Comment: somehow I can't match up the logs with the logging calls that produced them. Are we looking at the code that produced this log?

Comment: Please don't include the expected behavior in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: This looks wrong: `pulled[i].data = a[c];`. The index of `a` is the `c` object?

Comment: @jan - according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects using the dot syntax is correct

Comment: @renan - thank you for the recommendation - post is now edited as you suggested

Comment: @toy the dot syntax might be correct, but it's highly inefficient. The literal syntax is prefered whenever possible. That's what literal syntax exists for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aha!
thanks @beterraba and @jan dvorak for encouraging me to do a fiddle

because of that 
i found out that i had declared my "pulled" var incorrectly

i had initially had this:

```
    var pulled = new Array();
```

and instead it should have been this:

```
var pulled = new Object();
```

this now works as expected

also i incorporated @jan suggestions about object literal declaration
just for good measure!

Comment: Many people like using the shorthand version of those declarations ;) instead of using `var pulled = new Array();`, you may use just `var pulled = [];` - similarly, `var pulled = new Object();` may be written just like this: `var pulled = {};`. Just a tip if you wish to keep your code shorter.

Comment: @renan - thx for the tip. actually im slightly dyslexic so i do that on purpose so i dont read things wrong =:-)